# What is the TOTAL DAILY limit for Google Apps Script?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, limit

We know that the limit is **6 minute / execution**. Fine!

My code runs in 1 to max. 4 minutes, once every 30 minutes.

Clearly, even the max 4 minutes is less than the 6 minute limit per execution. Yet I get the following error message sometimes:

`Service using too much computer time for one day`

***So, what is the TOTAL DAILY limit for all executions combined?***

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to the [official documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/quotas):

> Service using too much computer time for one day. This indicates that
> the script exceeded the total allowable execution time for one day. It
> most commonly occurs for scripts that run on a trigger, which have a
> lower daily limit than scripts executed manually.

Again on the same page, you can see that there is the following limitation on the total time you can run a script via triggers:

[image]

Therefore, if you have a consumer account you can only run a script via trigger for 90 minutes.

Comment: Thanks @Marios for your fast response. So now that I'm using a free google account, it means my daily quota is 90 minutes; right?

Comment: Exactly. But this limitation concerns only trigger time.

Comment: Thanks again @Marios. One more question if you don't mind: Why does my code runtime change so much? From 1 minute to 4 minutes !??

Comment: @Omid1989 hmm it could be your spreadsheet file gets heavier or even Google might give smaller speeds from time to time. I would advice you to post part or your code in a new question if you think your code could be optimized better.

Comment: Thanks a lot @Marios for your help.